# Replacing column values in data frame, not included in list

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in R, like this:

```
fruits
   X1  X2     X3
   aa  kiwi  15
   ba  orange 25
   cc  lemon  23
   ba  apple  17
   cc  lemon  19
   cc  orange  18
   cc  orange 21
   ba  banana  17
```

I'd like to replace all values in column X2 except "orange" and "lemon" with "other". How to do it in R?

Example data:

```
fruits <- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("aa", "ba", "cc"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("apple", "banana", "kiwi", 
"lemon", "orange"), class = "factor"), X3 = c(15L, 25L, 23L, 
17L, 19L, 18L, 21L, 17L)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a variable indicating the rows to be altered. You can do this e.g. like this:

```
shouldBecomeOther<-!(fruits$X2 %in% c("orange", "lemon"))
```

Then use that indexer:

```
fruits$X2[shouldBecomeOther]<- "other"
```

Note that if the column is a factor (highly likely), it will take some more work, like this:

```
tmp<-as.character(fruits$x2)
tmp[shouldBecomeOther]<-"other"
fruits$x2<-factor(tmp)
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to coerce the factor to a character vector, then identify which elements are not in the required classes and replace them with `"other"`, and finally coerce back to a factor.

There are two variations on this theme, the first using the `replace()` function:

```
transform(fruits,
          X2 = factor(replace(as.character(X2), 
                              list = !X2 %in% c("orange","lemon"),
                              values = "other")))
```

which gives:

```
> transform(fruits, X2 = factor(replace(as.character(X2), 
+                                       list = !X2 %in% c("orange","lemon"),
+                                       values = "other")))
  X1     X2 X3
1 aa  other 15
2 ba orange 25
3 cc  lemon 23
4 ba  other 17
5 cc  lemon 19
6 cc orange 18
7 cc orange 21
8 ba  other 17
```

Or you can do it by hand:

```
fruits <- transform(fruits, 
                    X2 = {x <- as.character(X2)
                          x[!x %in% c("orange","lemon")] <- "other"
                          factor(x)})
> fruits
  X1     X2 X3
1 aa  other 15
2 ba orange 25
3 cc  lemon 23
4 ba  other 17
5 cc  lemon 19
6 cc orange 18
7 cc orange 21
8 ba  other 17
```

I use `transform()` here so that we do the manipulation inside an environment where `X2` is visible without having to use things like `fruits$X2` which gets tedious to type out.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
R> fruits = data.frame(X1 = 1:3, X2 = c("kiwi", "orange", "lemon"))
R> fruits$X2 = as.character(fruits$X2)
R> fruits[!(fruits$X2 %in% c("lemon", "orange")),]$X2 = "Other"
R> fruits
  X1     X2
1  1  Other
2  2 orange
3  3  lemon
```

In the above solution, I converted the factors to "characters". You don't have to do this, you can also:

1. When you create a data frame, use the argument stringsAsFactors = FALSE
2. If you use `read.csv`, use the stringsAsFactors
3. You work with factors directly:

   ```
   R> fruits$X2 = factor(fruits$X2, levels = c(as.character(fruits$X2), "Other"))
   R> fruits[!(fruits$X2 %in% c("lemon", "orange")),]$X2 = "Other"
   R> fruits
     X1     X2
   1  1  Other
   2  2 orange
   3  3  lemon
   ```

   Notice that I extend the levels of the first factor in line 1.