# Replace specific characters in a variable in data frame in R

Tags: r, string, replace, dataframe

I want to replace all `,`, `-`, `)`, `(` and (space) with `.` from the variable DMA.NAME in the example data frame. I referred to three posts and tried their approaches but all failed.:

[Replacing column values in data frame, not included in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818893/replacing-column-values-in-data-frame-not-included-in-list)

[R replace all particular values in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503266/r-replace-all-particular-values-in-a-data-frame)

[Replace characters from a column of a data frame R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187603/replace-characters-from-a-column-of-a-data-frame-r)

Approach 1

```
> shouldbecomeperiod <- c$DMA.NAME %in% c("-", ",", " ", "(", ")")
c$DMA.NAME[shouldbecomeperiod] <- "."
```

Approach 2

```
> removetext <- c("-", ",", " ", "(", ")")
c$DMA.NAME <- gsub(removetext, ".", c$DMA.NAME)
c$DMA.NAME <- gsub(removetext, ".", c$DMA.NAME, fixed = TRUE)

Warning message:
In gsub(removetext, ".", c$DMA.NAME) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Approach 3

```
> c[c == c(" ", ",", "(", ")", "-")] <- "."
```

Sample data frame

```
> df
DMA.CODE                  DATE                   DMA.NAME       count
111         22 8/14/2014 12:00:00 AM               Columbus, OH     1
112         23 7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM Orlando-Daytona Bch-Melbrn     1
79          18 7/30/2014 12:00:00 AM        Boston (Manchester)     1
99          22 8/20/2014 12:00:00 AM               Columbus, OH     1
112.1       23 7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM Orlando-Daytona Bch-Melbrn     1
208         27 7/31/2014 12:00:00 AM       Minneapolis-St. Paul     1
```

I know the problem - `gsub` uses pattern and only first element . The other two approaches are searching the entire variable for the exact value instead of searching within value for specific characters.

Comment: `gsub` looks for *all* matches.  `sub` is the one that only matches the first

Comment: yep! Thanks. I was using it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the special groups `[:punct:]` and `[:space:]` inside of a pattern group (`[...]`) like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  DMA.NAME = c(
    "Columbus, OH",
    "Orlando-Daytona Bch-Melbrn",
    "Boston (Manchester)",
    "Columbus, OH",
    "Orlando-Daytona Bch-Melbrn",
    "Minneapolis-St. Paul"),
  stringsAsFactors=F)
##
> gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]+","\\.",df$DMA.NAME)
[1] "Columbus.OH"                "Orlando.Daytona.Bch.Melbrn" "Boston.Manchester."         "Columbus.OH"               
[5] "Orlando.Daytona.Bch.Melbrn" "Minneapolis.St.Paul"
```

Comment: thanks! and the [:punct:] groups are mentioned here : http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html

Answer (score 3):

If your data frame is big you might want to look at this fast function from [`stringi`](http://stringi.rexamine.com) package. This function replaces every character of specific class for another. In this case character class is `L` - letters (inside `{}`), but big `P` (before `{}`) indicates that we are looking for the complements of this set, so for every non letter character. Merge indicates that consecutive matches should be merged into a single one.

```
require(stringi)
stri_replace_all_charclass(df$DMA.NAME, "\\P{L}",".", merge=T)
## [1] "Columbus.OH"                "Orlando.Daytona.Bch.Melbrn" "Boston.Manchester."         "Columbus.OH"               
## [5] "Orlando.Daytona.Bch.Melbrn" "Minneapolis.St.Paul"
```

And some benchmarks:

```
x <- sample(df$DMA.NAME, 1000, T)
gsubFun <- function(x){
    gsub("[[:punct:][:space:]]+","\\.",x)   
}

striFun <- function(x){
    stri_replace_all_charclass(x, "\\P{L}",".", T)  
}


require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(gsubFun(x), striFun(x))
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min        lq   median        uq       max neval
 gsubFun(x) 3472.276 3511.0015 3538.097 3573.5835 11039.984   100
 striFun(x)  877.259  893.3945  907.769  929.8065  3189.017   100
```